# What is the most starred message in TRPG General Chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, just-for-fun

I can't seem to find a way to sort starred messages from [TRPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat). I want to know what message has the most stars. So yeah, this is supposed to be a fun post.

Answers should include a link to the message and a quote block containing the message text, *and a screen shot showing the number of stars at time of posting*, as the post could possibly contribute to additional stars.

Most stars wins.

Comment: I'd also recommend a screenshot of the message to preserve it before the meta effect kicks in, similar to what is done here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279979

Answer (score 11):

By the power of <strike>Grayskull</strike> manual scrolling!

[This post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=37119567#37119567) seems to have the most stars with 20:

> Congratulations @doppelgreener and @nitsua60, and thank you to everyone who participated in the diamond election."

> [image: first message with 20 stars]

And [this post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=20635477#20635477) comes in second place with <strike>18</strike> 19:

> rpg.se should just have a big banner at the top that says "have you tried talking to the problem player?"

> [image: second message with 19 stars]

At the time of original posting, the above message had 18 stars:

> [image: second message when it still had 18 stars]

Comment: Where *is* that banner anyway?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Actually, the Stack Overlords are rolling out [new styles of community promotion ads (meta.se link)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/311001), including a banner. Evil me steeples his fingers and wonders if we couldn't make that chat-message a banner on our site....

Comment: @nitsua60 or kill two birds at once: an invitation to chat with that as the picture.